# How do I compare two columns of names in a spread sheet?

Tags: excel, set-difference

Good day to anyone who can help!

I have two long columns in excel of employee names stretching over 1000 in each one. They are not in any order.

One column shows a list of employees who worked for the company 10th January and the other column shows who works for the company 10th February. Now there will be leavers and there will be new starts so the names and amount of employees will have changed.

Is there a way in an excel spreadsheet to highlight this difference? Whether it highlights all the names that match or it highlights the names that don't. I need a way of finding out the difference between the two columns to show essentially who has left the company as keeping this record of who has left isn't available. All I can get is a list of current employees and when they have started. I need to find who has left in between the two dates.

I hope this makes sense.

Many Thanks

Comment: Would "install cygwin, write each column to a text file, sort the files, and let *comm* do the work for you" be an acceptable answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If each list contains only uniques, then Conditional Formatting with two rules may suit:

ColumnA:  `=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)<>1`
ColumnB:  `=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)<>1`

each applied to the occupied range of the respective column.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using VLOOKUP twice - it basically searchs a given list for a value and returns something if the value is found. If it does not find the value, it returns #NV
So, you create two new columns: Number One contains a vlookup for january, the scond one for february.
The rest is conditional formatting.